# Post New Checkbox values to db after edited

Tags: php, mysql

I have a edit form that has some checkboxes on it and I am having trouble getting the new checkbox values posted back to the db after it has been changed.  So far the form will load in the current values in the db but after you click different check boxes it wont update the change in the db. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

/*

EDIT.PHP

Allows user to edit specific entry in database

*/



// creates the edit record form

// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

function renderForm($id, $firstname, $contactname, $phone, $type, $sex, $markers, $error)

{

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Edit Record</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php

// if there are any errors, display them

if ($error != '')

{

echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

}

?>



<form action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

<div>

<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>

<strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Contact Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="contactname" value="<?php echo $contactname; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Phone Number: *</strong> <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Type: *</strong> 
<select name="type">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="Inpatient Hospital" <?php if($type=="Inpatient Hospital")echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Inpatient Hospital</option>
  <option value="Residential Facility"<?php if($type=="Residential Facility")echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Residential Facility</option>
  <option value="Behavioral Treatment Facility"<?php if($type=="Behavioral Treatment Facility")echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Behavioral Treatment Facility</option>
  <option value="Therapeutic Group Home"<?php if($type=="Therapeutic Group Home")echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Therapeutic Group Home</option>
  <option value="Drug or Addictions Rehab"<?php if($type=="Drug or Addictions Rehab")echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Drug or Addictions Rehab</option>
</select><br/>

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" <?php echo ($sex=="Male")?'checked="checked"':'' ?>size="17">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" <?php echo ($sex=="Female")?'checked="checked"':'' ?> size="17">Female
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Both" <?php echo ($sex=="Both")?'checked="checked"':'' ?> size="17">Both<br/>

<strong>Markers: *</strong> <input type="text" name="markers" value="<?php echo $markers; ?>"/><br/>






<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","un","pw","childcare");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FMarkers FROM faci WHERE ID='$id'"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $focus=explode(",",$row['FMarkers']);

?>
Autism<input type="checkbox" name="FMarkers[]" value="Autism" <?php if(in_array("Autism",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
Attachement Disorder<input type="checkbox" name="FMarkers[]" value="Attachement Disorder" <?php if(in_array("Attachement Disorder",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
Dissociative Disorder<input type="checkbox" name="FMarkers[]" value="Dissociative Disorder" <?php if(in_array("Dissociative Disorder",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
ODD<input type="checkbox" name="FMarkers[]" value="ODD" <?php if(in_array("ODD",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >
ADHD<input type="checkbox" name="FMarkers[]" value="ADHD" <?php if(in_array("ADHD",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >

<?php
//print_r(array_values($focus));

//echo("<pre>\n");
//print_r($_POST);
//echo("</pre>\n");

//var_dump($dog);


//these below are different ways I have tried to get it to work

//$markers = implode(',', $_POST['dog']);

//$markers=$_POST['focus'];
//$markers = implode(",",$markers);

//$markers = implode(",",$_POST['focus']);

//$check = isset($_POST['focus']) ? $_POST['focus'] : '';
//$markers = is_array($check) ? implode(", ", $check) : '';

//echo $markers;


?>

<?php

}
?>




<p>* Required</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

}







// connect to the database

include('connect-db.php');



// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$id = $_POST['id'];

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));

$contactname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contactname']));

$phone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));

$type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']));

$sex = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sex']));

$markers = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['markers']));

// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in

if ($firstname == '' || $contactname == '')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';



//error, display form

renderForm($id, $firstname, $contactname, $phone, $type, $sex, $markers, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

mysql_query("UPDATE faci SET FName='$firstname', FContact='$contactname', FPhone='$phone', FType='$type', FSex='$sex', FMarkers='$markers' WHERE ID='$id'")

or die(mysql_error());



// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: facility-view.php");

}

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

echo 'Error!';

}

}

else

// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form

{



// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

{

// query db

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faci WHERE ID=$id")

or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);



// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse

if($row)

{



// get data from db

$firstname = $row['FName'];

$contactname = $row['FContact'];

$phone = $row['FPhone'];

$type = $row['FType'];

$sex = $row['FSex'];

$markers = $row['FMarkers'];



// show form

renderForm($id, $firstname, $contactname, $phone, $type, $sex, $markers, '');

}

else

// if no match, display result

{

echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}

}

?>
```

Comment: the question is how are you updating the values on your DB?

Comment: I am using this to post to the db at the end of the form 
    mysql_query("UPDATE faci SET FName='$firstname', 
    FContact='$contactname', FPhone='$phone', FType='$type', 
    FSex='$sex', FMarkers='$markers' WHERE ID='$id'")

    or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I have tried to use the implode command to put the array back together to post it and havent been able to get it to work.

Comment: do you even submit the form after the updates? you should include this from your post, current post in not really helpful, update your post please

Comment: ok no problem, I have edit the code area to include everything in the file that I am working in.